# Link to a different web page contains too many parameters

Tags: asp.net, web, codecharge

I have a link from a web page to another, and the link is supposed to only send a single parameter (PackageName). But here's what happens, the linked web page is being called with 2 params:

.../ETL/JobsLogSpec.aspx?PackageName=Loan_History_Summary_Make_Table&NoDays=10

The NoDays is the unwanted parameter, it is a field in the initial web page, used in a search. Other pages in that app exhibit similar behaviour (too many params). I used a code generator to develop these (CodeCharge), here's the code:

```
 <tr class="Row">
      <td><mt:MTLabel Source="TaskName" ID="TaskName" runat="server"/></td> 
      <td><mt:MTLink Source="PackageName" ID="PackageName" runat="server" HrefSource="~/JobsLogSpec.aspx" PreserveParameters="Get"><Parameters>
        <mt:UrlParameter Name="PackageName" SourceType="DataSourceColumn" Source="PackageName"/>
      </Parameters></mt:MTLink></td>
```

I don't see a problem with this code (but I am a beginner). Can this be something that the server does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used this product before, but from a quick Google, it seems the issue is that your `ItemLink` is preserving parameters via the `PreserveParameters="Get"` attribute.

Either remove the `PreserveParameters="Get"` attribute completely.

OR

Change your code to `PreserveParameters="None"`.

UPDATE:

Apparently, there is a designer that allows you to visually change these values as well:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're right, it's working! I rarely find anything about Codecharge by googling (or in their forum), so that I gave up. Looks like I shouldn't have. thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it is hard to find these things. Good luck with your code. Feel free to up-vote answers as well. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To add to the accepted answer, which is entirely right, the reasoning behind the automatic adding of the parameters appears to be that most of the time the parameters will be needed again, and they will remain unless specifically removed. There is usually no problem with having extra querystring parameters if the page doesn't use it - it just keeps turning up (see below for problem).

The 'Preserve Parameters' is usually used to turn on or off all the GET and/or POST values, but individual parameters may be removed by typing them into the 'Remove Parameters' field just above it (semi-colon delimited).

One issue I had was two pages using grids called 'employee' and by default the page selection is a querystring parameter like 'employee_GridPage=2', and so page 2 selected on the first page would also show page 2 if the second page was shown. My solution was to change one grid to 'employees'. I could have also added 'employee_GridPage' to the 'Remove Parameters' on links from the first page.